# <script> tag inside a javascript or jquery (in Sharepoint (office 360))

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, src

At the moment I am coding in sharepoint(office 360), and I am having so many issues with the site considering that its my first week to use it. First of all when i tried to use a < script > tag in my codes, sharepoint seems to block this, and does not recognize my scripts. I know that there is a way to unblock the < script > tag, but I want to concentrate on the coding part.

OK, now to the issue, at the moment I am using every codes that I can gather to put < script > tags inside my javascript/jquery. I am putting my codes inside  an onclick event, considering that the site does not allow me to use < script > tag.

I tried to use this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="new_workflow_doc_handler" onclick="<input type="hidden" name="new_workflow_doc_handler" onclick="$('#content').html('<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The script is running');<\/script>');">
```

this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="new_workflow_doc_handler" onclick="document.write('<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The script is running');<\/script>')">
```

this

```
<input type="hidden" name="new_workflow_doc_handler" onclick="var scriptString = '<script>alert('The script is running');</script>'; $(scriptString).appendTo('#content');">
```

Unfortunately all the codes i have tried was no success.
and one of the big issues that I dont like about this is that when inside the onclick event I cant use double qoutes.

If you are wondering why I a want to put a < script > tag inside the javascript, as what I have said in the first place, sharepoint does not allow me to use < script > tags and I want to use script tag because I want to source something.

like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ntp-a1.nict.go.jp/cgi-bin/jsont'></script>
```

What syntax do i use to put a < script > tag inside my onclick event?

or is there other ways to "src" without using the < script > tag in javascript/jquery on an onclick event.

or is it possible, because sharepoint is kinda fussy when it comes to syntax coding. so many does and dont.

Comment: I'm not a SharePoint expert, but are you sure that the server isn't specifically configured to filter out Javascript, for example, to prevent cross site scripting vulnerabilities? If it is, you might as well give up and find a more appropriate host for your Web application.

Comment: I really don't know though, I have been in this hosting site for 2 weeks now. and never had any idea about filtering javascript.