# Get the "Current" UTC date and Time. Independent in Local Time/Computer Time

Tags: javascript, utc

Okay, I know this seems redundant and maybe i miss something. But all I see in stackoverflow that gets UTC date are Local Time dependent or Computer Time dependent.

such as:

```
var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC());
```

..

```
var today = new Date();
var YY = today.getUTCFullYear();
var MM = today.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var DD = today.getUTCDate();
var h = today.getUTCHours();
var m = today.getUTCMinutes();
```

I guess because of the "Date()" which is dependent on Local Time\Computer Time. I know I am noob at this, but I think thats how it works.

Now I want to fetch the "CURRENT" (UTC date and time), which is not dependent on local/computer time.

Because when I tried to run the codes, the UTC date and time changes when I tried to configure my computer time. It clearly is dependent on Local\Computer time.

How do I do it?

Comment: Two things to note: 1) they shouldn't change if you are changing your PC timezone and not your PC time and 2) typically this would be done serverside where you have control over the hardware and not clientside (i.e. saving data with UTC timezone)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete example of using the time server to get the GMT datetime

```
function getTime(zone, success) {
var url = 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=' + zone,
    ud = 'json' + (+new Date());
window[ud]= function(o){
    success && success(new Date(o.datetime), o);
};
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild((function(){
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = url + '&callback=' + ud;
    return s;
})
```

Here is a jquery version

```
$.getTime = function(zone, success) {
var url = 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz='
        + zone + '&callback=?';
$.getJSON(url, function(o){
    success && success(new Date(o.datetime), o);
});};
```

Then just call it.

```
$.getTime('GMT', function(time){alert(time);});
```

Comment: As what I have said in my question, and qoute "Get the “Current” UTC date and Time. Independent in Local Time/Computer Time".

It seems in your answer that  utcDate.getTime()  depends on the computer/local time. I tried to run it, but unfortunately it keeps changing and adapting to my system time when I tried to change it.

Comment: if you want the GMT time without relying on using the computers clock, you'll have to hit a server in order to get it.  In that case, why not just do this?  Wrap this in a script tag and parse the datetime out of the json returned.   http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=GMT

Comment: One of my big issue at the moment. see my first post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935278/script-tag-inside-a-javascript-or-jquery-in-sharepoint-office-360?noredirect=1#comment47996946_29935278). I am on a webhosting site where I cannot use a script tag. Thats why I am eager to find another way around. Or is it possible? 
I guess my problem is impossible.

Comment: If your not able to use a script tag, I think you are stuck taking the local utc datetime and applying the offset hours each time its needed in a function

Comment: this may work for you  http://webbrewers.com/adding-javascript-to-an-office-365-sharepoint-2013-public-web-page-7/