# Get Current Date and Time from a server(any server). limited to javascript only

Tags: javascript

I found some source codes out there for fetching date/time from a server, but unfortunately it is using php tags, ssi, etc. And I am on sharepoint w/c is a  web hosting site, it pisses me off for the fact that it doesn't allow me to use < script > tags, php tags, and the likes. one of my problems can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935278/script-tag-inside-a-javascript-or-jquery-in-sharepoint-office-360?noredirect=1#comment47996946_29935278).

And if you have any ideas how.
I would rather not use any libraries and just pure javascript only. It is because of the pesky sharepoint.

Comment: If it's not letting you use `<script>`, I don't see how a JavaScript solution will help...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the SharePoint Object Model (client or server) to fetch the date and time. The SharePoint Server should provide you with the data and time in accordance with it's regional settings. However, as Amadan mentioned, if you can't use `<script>` tags, you're kind of screwed. You could place a JavaScript file in your Asset Library, but you'll still have to load it and that'll be an issue. You may look into the Content Editor Web Part and inputting your javascript there. There's a chance it could work there.

I'm not sure what your use case is or what you want to do with said date/time, but you may want to consider this as it will be a driver in which methodology you'll want to use. If it's a SharePoint App, you've got all the tools you need. If it's just for your own purposes, you could look into the SharePoint Web Services and invoke that to get the Date and Time in an external program outside of SharePoint.